# Why isn't my instance_table.row_data object updating in Kivy MDDataTable?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm creating a simple scorecard app but am having trouble accessing my cell values as they're updated.

When I create the table, using the `create_table` method, I print the value of the columns through `column_sums` and all looks correct (a list of tuples with '0' in them). However, when I open the popup and update the table with a new number it updates on the screen but when I then call the `update_cell` function and try to access the table data, through `instance_table.row_data` it still prints a list of tuples with '0' in them, the values I see on screen aren't coming through in that function.

I've tried re-summing the values through `column_sums` as I did in the `create_table` method but I still get a list of tuples with '0' in them. Am I doing something wrong by updating the `text` property of the `CellRow`? I was unable to find a property called `value` or something.

```
class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None
    text_field = None

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [LandingWindow(name="landing"), NewGameWindow(name="new_game"), ScorecardWindow(name="scorecard"),]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "landing" #set to "landing"
        return self.sm

    def button_pressed(self, *args):
        for a in args:
            try:
                self.text_field.text += a.text
            except:
                pass

    def update_cell(self, instance_row, instance_table, text_field, *args):
        instance_row.text = text_field.text
        print(instance_table.row_data)


    def close(self):
        Example.get_running_app().sm.current = "landing"
        #TODO delete the data from the page

    def open_popup(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.text_field = TextInput(size_hint_y=0.25)
        box.add_widget(self.text_field)
        grid = GridLayout(cols=3)
        numeric_keypad = ['7', '8', '9', '4', '5', '6', '1', '2', '3', '.', '0', 'OK']
        for x in numeric_keypad:
            if str(x) == 'OK':
                ok_button = Button(text=str(x))
                grid.add_widget(ok_button)
            else:
                number_button = Button(text=str(x))
                number_button.bind(on_release=self.button_pressed)
                grid.add_widget(number_button)
        box.add_widget(grid)
        popup = Popup(title="Enter Your Score", content=box, size_hint=(0.5,0.5))
        ok_button.bind(on_release=lambda *args: self.update_cell(instance_row, instance_table, self.text_field, *args), on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()

    def create_table(self):
        game_name = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['game_name'].text
        rounds = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['rounds'].value
        players = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['players'].value
        players = int(players)
        rounds = int(rounds)
        round_list = [("0",) * players for _ in range(rounds)]
        table = MDDataTable(
            rows_num=len(round_list),
            column_data=[(f"Player {x + 1}", dp(20)) for x in range(players)],
            row_data=round_list,
            on_row_press = self.open_popup
        )
        column_sums = [sum(int(row_data[column_index]) for row_data in table.row_data) for column_index in
                       range(players)]
        table.bind(on_row_press=self.open_popup)
        self.root.get_screen("scorecard").ids['add_table_to_scrollview'].add_widget(table)
        self.sm.current = "scorecard"

        print(column_sums)


Example().run()
```

UPDATE:

Through **many** rounds of ChatGPT I was able to get to a point where the table updates (on screen and in the list of tuples that's printed in `column_sums`). However, the code updates the cell index in order, starting at [0], the first cell. For example, if I select the 14th cell, it will update the first cell. Then if I update the 5th cell, it will update the second cell, and so on. Many more rounds of ChatGPT couldn't solve this issue!

Here's the updated code of the `update_cell` function:

```
    def update_cell(self, instance_row, instance_table, text_field, *args):
        #instance_row.text = text_field.text # This updates the correct cell and appears on the screen but isn't actually updating the values in the list of tuples.

        print("row clicked is: ", instance_row)
        # Split the instance_row.text into individual elements
        row_text_elements = instance_row.text.split(',')

        # Find the row_index corresponding to instance_row.text
        row_index = -1
        for index, row_data in enumerate(instance_table.row_data):
            if all(element in row_data for element in row_text_elements):
                row_index = index
                break

        if row_index != -1:
            # Find the cell_index corresponding to instance_row.text
            cell_index = -1
            row_data_list = list(instance_table.row_data[row_index])
            for index, element in enumerate(row_data_list):
                if element == instance_row.text:
                    cell_index = index
                    break

            if cell_index != -1:
                # Update the cell value in the row
                row_data_list[cell_index] = text_field.text
                instance_table.row_data[row_index] = tuple(row_data_list)
                print("row index: ", instance_table.row_data[row_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up your update:

The issue seems in the way you are determining the `cell_index`. In the updated implementation, you are comparing the entire `instance_row.text` with each particular element in the `row_data_list`, giving an incorrect `cell_index`.

Try using `col_num` attribute of `instance_row` to get the `cell_index`. This attribute will give you the column number of cell clicked.

Make the following change:

```
def update_cell(self, instance_row, instance_table, text_field, *args):

print("row clicked is: ", instance_row)
row_text_elements = instance_row.text.split(',')

row_index = -1
for index, row_data in enumerate(instance_table.row_data):
    if all(element in row_data for element in row_text_elements):
        row_index = index
        break

if row_index != -1:
    cell_index = instance_row.col_num # <--- make this change

    row_data_list = list(instance_table.row_data[row_index])
    row_data_list[cell_index] = text_field.text
    instance_table.row_data[row_index] = tuple(row_data_list)
    print("row index: ", instance_table.row_data[row_index])
```

Please let me know if the issue still persist.